How to go about making hitboxes in Roblox
Lately, I had been trying to figure out how to make a decent hitbox system for my game. My inspiration is "Item Asylum". What I had noticed is: The hitbox doesn't move with the player, instead multiple are created and as well as I can understand, destroyed. That's no the tricky part, the tricky part is: making it not damage the person who activated the ability / created the hitbox.
Or, do I just make it move with the character (which will probably a worse decision since exploiters can use that to their advantage.)

It's a little hard to tell what you're asking. Please read [ask] for more information on what kind of details you need. It also seems like your questions could use a [mre].

Is there a reason the existing BasePart.Touched event is insufficient for what you're trying to do? A player's character model is a collection of Parts, and each Part has its own Touched event. That is to say, every part has its own hitbox that is managed by the engine so you don't have to. So what is driving you to reinvent this wheel in particular?

Basically, part that when touched damages the person who touches it, appears in front of the attacker, shouldn't damage them when touched. Figured out how to do this a while ago, just wanted to make it clear what I meant.

You could use a part surrounding the object/model/part to which you would like to give a hitbox. Here are a few details on how to do that. Create a normal part and resize it to what you want, covering the model with the hitbox. Set the CanCollide property to false.  Weld the hitbox to the part you want to have a hitbox. Insert a script to check for the Touched event then connect a function.  Example:
local hitbox=script.parent
hitbox.Touched:Connect(function()
    print("object touched"!)
    
    end)


Hope this helps!

Also, this question should be in the Game Dev Site. Ask questions like this over there.

Dev Site requires you to read like 1500 posts and comment on them and after that you can post. As for the answer, thanks. Although I meant so that it doesn't damage the attackers character, since welding it to the character makes it so that people can just go unga bunga with flying exploits, or just start turning a thousand times for tons of damage.

@RelaxingGaming you shoudn't need to. You should be able to ask questions straight away, like stack overflow. If you have the wrong website, look here:https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
